# Extract Date from a file name

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a column called FileName and I wanted extract the date from the column as a Date column.

FileName
M:\Mapping\Workforce_Planning\ABC\ABClrmp.full.20160107.csv

Desired Result

Date
2016-01-07

I wanted to know the most efficient way.

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Below query :  Even File name is changed .. it will return correct output.

```
            select cast(SUBSTRING(filename,(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',filename)),8) as DATE) 

            select CONVERT(datetime, cast(SUBSTRING(filename,(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',filename)),8) as DATE), 103)
```

sample code  :

```
            CREATE TABLE #tmpTable(id INT, FileName  nvarchar(250))
            INSERT INTO #tmpTable values
            (1, 'M:\Mapping\Workforce_Planning\ABC\ABClrmp.full.20160107.csv'),
            (2, 'M:\Mapping\.20160207.csv')

            select cast(SUBSTRING(filename,(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',filename)),8) as DATE) from #tmpTable

            -- Or
            select CONVERT(datetime, cast(SUBSTRING(filename,(PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',filename)),8) as DATE), 103)
            from #tmpTable
```

Comment: I get the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. The column Filename is nvarchar(260).

Comment: which version you are using ?

Comment: I got the same error. I'm using SQL Dedicated pool on synapse

Answer (score 3):

If that is your format, then this might be the best way:

```
select cast(left(right(filename, 12), 8) as date)
```